# Receiving Windows Message from Thread after it has been destroyed

Tags: windows, multithreading, message

I am using an FTP client in a seperate thread. The FTP client uses a job list to up-/download files to a connected server. If the thread wants to communicate with my main thread it will use an event queue. The thread will create an event, put it into the queue and then post a windows message to my main thread telling me that there are new events in the queue.
The main thread then fetches the latest event from the queue and removes it. The queue is held in the thread object but I am using a lock to make it thread-safe.
I created a function within my main thread which is listening for messages from the FTP thread. I also registered a handle for this method (via AllocateHwnd()) so that the thread is posting it's messages excactly to the listening method of my main thread.

Now I want to know if the following scenario is possible:

I destroy the thread. Right before it gets destroyed the thread will post a windows message to the main thread because there is a new event. The windows message however has some delay (for whatever reason). Now the thread gets destroyed and the thread object is gone. Of course, the event queue is also gone. The main thread now receives the delayed windows message telling him that there is a new event in the queue. It tries to fetch the queue which will result in an invalid pointer operation since there the queue and the thread object have been free'd.

To avoid this problem, I implemented a check into my message listening method. Right before I access the event queue from the thread I will check if the thread still exists. If yes, then I access the event queue, if no, then I will simply drop the message.

However, what if the thread gets destroyed right after I checked it, but before I access the queue. The sequence would be like this:

- Check if thread exists
- (thread gets destroyed NOW)
- Access event queue

Can this scenario still happen? I know that this does sound like a very specific and tiny scenario since the thread would have to get destroyed right between those two commands in order to fail but I want to make sure that I do not access the event queue when the thread is actually not existing anymore.

I hope I could explain my problem well enough. Thanks in advance for any provided answers.

Comment: Btw I could solve this problem if I use SendMessage instead of PostMessage, right? However if I want to handle the sent messages this might block my FTP thread for quite a while depending on how long the message handling method takes. Is that correct?

Comment: Why do you not simply pass the event object in the Windows message?  A pointer to it in lParam or wParam, (or both)? Why are you using a Windows message queue to signal that some object is waiting in yet another queue?

Comment: What is this event object, how big is it?

Comment: I used to do it like this, however I read on this plattform that it is also possible to do it with the queue so I wanted to try out this approach. It now hit me that there might be a synchronisation problem with the queue. I guess I will go back to the old approach like you suggested, but I am just curious if the queue-approach can also work.

There event object can be of different typed btw. For example, I want to send an event if the FTP server disconnects so that the main thread an destroy the FTP thread. Also I want to trigger an event if a job is done.

Comment: You can make it work by ensuring that the queue instance is not owned by the thread and so is not destroyed with it.  Pass the queue object as a ctor parameter to the thread, and make sure that the thread does not destroy it.  The reciept of the last 'WM_ThreadTerminated', (or whatever), message by the main threa\d could destroy the queue.

Comment: BTW, I've seem this 'use a separate thread-safe queue' thing before.  I've never understood the rationale behind it. It's another pile of locking, and other gunge, for no aparrent reason.

Comment: Also: ' I want to send an event if the FTP server disconnects so that the main thread an destroy the FTP thread' - why can the FTP thread not destroy itself after freeing all its internal FTP resources and sending its final message?  Why should the main thread have to do it?

Comment: The queue-approach can work, if you make the thread which create others thread also responsible of the queue life-time. Much simpler to PostMessage with heap memory, however. You already have a queue :-)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. How whould the thread destroy itself? I've never done it before. I currently have a component which holds and controls the thread instance. The thread instance holds the FTP client. The component (used in the main thread) connects to an FTP server using the thread's Connect() method. If the connection has been established, it starts the thread. The thread is checking the  job queue for available job. The component is adding jobs to the job queue. This is basically how my component and thread work.

You think it would be better for the thread to control itself?

Comment: You need to prevent the job queue from being destroyed if there are references to to it in the message queue. A reference count would work here.

Comment: Thank you for all of your advice. It is working just fine now. But one more question: The FTP thread is posting windows messages to give updates on the current job status. These messages are received by the FTP component in the main thread so that the user of the component can do progress bar updates while a job is being processed. I am worried if doing this progress bar updats via messages might flood the windows message quee since a lot of messages will be sent if you download a big file. Can that cause any problems?